# Hamburger icon not appearing on site from modified DW template

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, dreamweaver-templates

I am using Dreamweaver CC 2017 Bootstrap Starter Templates to re-design a site  I designed at least 12 years ago. I used the Starter Template Bootstrap E-Commerce and created a test page from it to test the collapsing menu with the hamburger icon appearing, no problem.
I proceeded to create the site and everything is fine except for the hamburger icon not appearing.
I have searched through the answers here and checked against what I have done but cannot find the anomaly. I have placed my site and the template side by side and still cannot see it.
I have tested it on Android as well as Windows.
I have not included the CSS in case it is in the code below but I will of course supply it on request.
Here is the page:

```html
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Fine Antique Clocks, Barometers &amp; Marine Chronometers - Archives</title>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url(../images/ancient_clock_2048_pl.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-color: rgba(229,207,111,0.7);
 background-size: cover;
}

</style>

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
</head>
<body>

<nav>
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="bada"><a href="http://www.bada.org/provenart/dealer.cgi?d_id=67&c_id=193" target="_blank"><img src="../images/BADA-logo-colour_round.jpg" class="img-circle img-responsive" alt="British Antique Dealers Association"></a></div>
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display --><br>
    <br>
    <img src="/images/patriccapon_antique_clocks.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive" alt="Placeholder image">
    
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> 
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
   <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
   <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
   <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
   </button>
   </div>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> </a> </div>
       <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="active"><a href="../antique_clocks_stock_01.html">Stock <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
       <li class="active"><a href="../antique_clocks_archives_01.html">Archives <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="../antique_clocks_services.html">Services <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
        <li><a href="../antique_clocks_news.html">News</a> </li>
        
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-sm">
        <li><a href="../antique_clocks_contact_us.html">Contact Us</a> </li>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-sm">
        <li><a href="../antique_clocks_links.html">About Us</a> </li>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-sm">
        <li><a href="../antique_clocks_links.html">Links</a> </li>
   <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
   </li></ul>
    </ul></ul></div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
  
  <!-- /.container-fluid --> 
 </nav><br>
```